# Why can't I use nth-child on mark tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Nothing in my code overwrites this selector, so I'm confused as to why it's not working. I've googled about it and asked a few friends and they don't know. I checked the server wasn't just taking a while to update the page by updating text and it seems fine.

CSS

```
mark {
    color: #CCC;
    background: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
mark:nth-child(even) {
    background: #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<p><mark>warri0r</mark>Yes</p>
<p><mark>j3w1sh</mark>No</p>
<p><mark>MrGuy</mark>I don't know</p>
<p><mark>explode_</mark>Maybe...</p>
<p><mark>USAUSAUSA</mark>Why not?</p>
<p><mark>Samuel01</mark>Absolutely</p>
```

Comment: `:nth-child` selects children by index within their parent.  In each paragraph you only have one `mark`, which has an `odd` index.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the mark element.

Comment: I just didn't know very well how nth-child worked, I know now there was nothing wrong with the mark element.

Comment: It should, perhaps be noted, be noted that it looks like you shouldn't be using the `mark` tag at all here...`<strong>` might be more appropriate. [**<mark> @MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark)

Comment: @Paulie_D: Not even that, since the OP isn't really trying to emphasize the respondents' names here - either `<b>` or just plain `<span>`. would be preferred http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#conversations Don't you just love HTML5 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mark:nth-child(even)` doesn't work because it is an only child of `<p>`.

Rewrite your CSS:

```
p:nth-child(even) mark {
    background: #000;
}
```

(select `<mark>` of even `<p>`)

http://jsfiddle.net/hbxk3owh/

Answer (score 1):

Because `:nth-child` looks for the parent element to find the child.

To easily understand it:

Wrap your code inside a div. Access the even paragraph using `nth-child(2n)` which is even children of the parent div `mark`.

*You need not have parent div `mask` for your case because `<body>` is the parent. Just for explanation purpose I have added the class `mask`*

```css
mark {
  color: #CCC;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.mark p:nth-child(even) mark {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mark">
  <p>
    <mark>warri0r</mark>Yes</p>
  <p>
    <mark>j3w1sh</mark>No</p>
  <p>
    <mark>MrGuy</mark>I don't know</p>
  <p>
    <mark>explode_</mark>Maybe...</p>
  <p>
    <mark>USAUSAUSA</mark>Why not?</p>
  <p>
    <mark>Samuel01</mark>Absolutely</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because nth-child use in a element like this:

```
mark {
  color: #CCC;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
mark:nth-child(even) {
  background: #000;
}

<p>
  <mark>warri0r</mark><span>Yes</span> <br>
  <mark>j3w1sh</mark><span<No</span> <br>
  <mark>MrGuy</mark><span>I don't know</span>
</p>
```

Now `p` element has 3 child in yourself.